# Composer autoload won't work after deployment

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am relatively new to using composer and autoload to organize my code. I have a git repository and on my local machine, I set up composer in the root dir of my project. I specified everything in a composer.json needed to get running. Using "`composer install`", all libraries are automatically installed.

```
{
    "name": "my/repo",
    "description": "bla",
    "version": "1.2.3",
    "require":
    {
        "php": "5.6.*",
        "geraintluff/jsv4": "1.*",
        "lcobucci/jwt": "^3.0"
    },
    "autoload":
    {
        "psr-4":
        {
            "MyNamespace\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

So - once I ran "`composer install`" on my local machine, everything was autoloaded in my code. Fine.

But now I need to deploy the whole thing on another linux system. So i pull from the git and run `composer install`. All the libraries are fetched and the autoload file shows up in `vendor/`

Yet, I cannot use autoload (yes, I did `require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');`). Everytime I try to instantiaze a class, i get a

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'X' not found in /var/www/bla/x.class.php on line 123
```

Using `use X;` does not solve the problem, nor does trying to instantiate the class with its full Namespace name (e.g. `$x = new \A\B\X();`)

Here is the folder structure (if this matters):

```
+ src/
| + X.class.php // namespace here is "MyNamespace"
| + Y.class.php // same namespace
+ test/
  + run.php // namespace is "Test"
```

Here is a snippet of this code (run.php):

```
<?php namespace Test; // different namespace than the rest of the code
// making the namespace also "\MyNamespace" wouldnt work either

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');

use \MyNamespace\Y; // whether this line is here or not does not change the error

session_start();

// same error as with "just" implements Y {}
class SomeClass implements \MyNamespace\Y {
    // ...
}

?>
```

So here, the Fatal error is thrown for the line where Y is extended. No matter if I use the full namespace or not. Only thing that will help is a require_once()...

So, this forces me to go back to the cumbersome way of doing all the require/includes myself!? Is there any way to solve this?

PS: `composer dumpautoload` wont help

PPS: `composer validate` shows no errors

Comment: Posting the snippet of PHP code that's giving you the error would help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Also posting the `composer.json` being responsible for autoloading the class would be necessary to evaluate any errors.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this has already been solved. The composer.json is also already listed above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PSR-4 compliance, your file structure should be:

```
+ src/
| + X.php
| + Y.php
```

Note the removal of the .class.php suffix. http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: Well this might be true due to the specification, but it didn't solve anything :(

Comment: WOW - just spent 1 full HOUR of restructuring the code just to fit to the said specification in every single bit and it solved... NOTHING >:(

Comment: Well, even if its not working (yet) getting your code to match PSR-4 specification is still a requirement for using a PSR-4 autoloader. Other gotchyas: linux is case sensitive but the mac os (if thats what you use) filesystem is not, so if your class is `X` and your file is `x.php` it will work on your mac but not in production. Are both of your classes declared to be in the "MyNamespace" namespace? There are lots of ways in which your current setup might not be working, rather than track those down (without seeing the code) I've made a [simple working example here](http://goo.gl/4y9aqU)

Comment: took me 2 full days to change all the code, but this is actually working

Comment: @Xenonite it would be useful for future arrivals (hello there..!) if you posted exactly what you had to change.